# Probability of deviation from the expected hitting time in a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given that the time to hit state $s_j$ starting from $s_i$ in a Markov process is $\tau$, what is the probability that in a simulation of the system, the actual hitting time is $\tau + \delta$, for some $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$?

EDIT:

Expected hitting time for a Markov process (assuming the transition matrix has been constructed) already has a [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Expected_hitting_times). It should be the case that there should also exist a closed-form expression for the probability of being $\delta$ far from the expected time.

Comment: This may be too general to answer. It depends a lot on the Markov process, on how big $\delta$ is in relationship to $\tau$ and on what sort of answer you'd like (exact is probably too much to hope for). Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @Misha happy to give more details, but forgive me what else is missing from my question? I added a little bit more information.